# Draw rectangle on touch in iOS subview

Tags: iphone, ios, sudoku

I'm trying to port a Sudoku app that I created in Cocoa over to iOS, and I'm having trouble translating the mouseDown events that I had in the Mac app into touchBegan events on iOS.

I have a subview created in the parent view that has the grid drawn and all the initial values of the Sudoku game in place. Whenever I try to tap on an empty square in the simulator to update the value, my console gives me these errors:

```
Mar 24 14:59:56 Macintosh-94.local SudokiOS[95817] <Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0
Mar 24 14:59:56 Macintosh-94.local SudokiOS[95817] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
Mar 24 14:59:56 Macintosh-94.local SudokiOS[95817] <Error>: CGContextSetFlatness: invalid context 0x0
Mar 24 14:59:56 Macintosh-94.local SudokiOS[95817] <Error>: CGContextAddPath: invalid context 0x0
Mar 24 14:59:56 Macintosh-94.local SudokiOS[95817] <Error>: CGContextDrawPath: invalid context 0x0
Mar 24 14:59:56 Macintosh-94.local SudokiOS[95817] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
```

Here is the (working) code from my mac app:

```
//SudokuView.m
-(void)paintSelectionRectangle
{
    CGFloat thirdWidth = self.bounds.size.width / 3.0;
    CGFloat thirdHeight = self.bounds.size.height / 3.0;
    CGFloat ninthWidth = thirdWidth / 3.0;
    CGFloat ninthHeight = thirdHeight / 3.0;

    NSRect selectionRect = NSMakeRect(_selectionCellX * thirdWidth + _selectionX * ninthWidth,
                                      _selectionCellY * thirdHeight + _selectionY * ninthHeight,
                                      ninthWidth, ninthHeight);

    NSColor* selectionColor = [NSColor colorWithSRGBRed: 0.0 green: 0.0 blue: 1.0
                               alpha: 0.5];
    [selectionColor setFill];

    NSBezierPath* selectionPath = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: selectionRect
                                                                  xRadius: ( ninthWidth / 4.0 )
                                                                  yRadius: ( ninthHeight / 4.0 )];
    [selectionPath fill];
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{

    ...

    if(_haveSelection)
    {
        [self paintSelectionRectangle];
    }
    ...
}
.
.
.
-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event
{
    NSPoint location = [event locationInWindow];
    CGFloat thirds = self.bounds.size.width / 3;
    CGFloat ninths = thirds / 3;

    _selectionCellX = (UInt32)(location.x/thirds);
    _selectionCellY = (UInt32)(location.y/thirds);
    _selectionX = (UInt32)((location.x - (_selectionCellX * thirds)) / ninths);
    _selectionY = (UInt32)((location.y - (_selectionCellY * thirds)) / ninths);

    _haveSelection = YES;


    if ([self._windowController isOriginalValueAtCellX:_selectionCellX andCellY:_selectionCellY xIndex:_selectionX yIndex:_selectionY] == NO)
    {
        _haveSelection = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        _haveSelection = NO;
    }
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

And this is what is not working in the iOS app

```
//SudokiOSViewController.m
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch* touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.sudokuSubview];
    CGFloat thirds = sudokuSubview.bounds.size.width / 3;
    CGFloat ninths = thirds / 3;


    _selectionCellX = (UInt32)(location.x/thirds);
    _selectionCellY = (UInt32)(location.y/thirds);
    _selectionX = (UInt32)((location.x - (_selectionCellX * thirds)) / ninths);
    _selectionY = (UInt32)((location.y - (_selectionCellY * thirds)) / ninths);
    _haveSelection = YES;
    if ([ourView._ourViewController isOriginalValueAtCellX:_selectionCellX andCellY:_selectionCellY xIndex:_selectionX yIndex:_selectionY] == NO)
    {
        _haveSelection = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        _haveSelection = NO;
    }

}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    [sudokuSubview setNeedsDisplay];
    [self paintSelectionRectangle];
}
```

I'm having a difficult time understanding whether I should be just using touchBegan and touchEnded or UIGestureRecognizer. I also don't understand why CGContext is being called. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

UPDATE: As mrueg suggested, here is the iOS code for `paintselectionrectangle` :

```
-(void)paintSelectionRectangle
{
    CGFloat thirdWidth = self.bounds.size.width / 3.0;
    CGFloat thirdHeight = self.bounds.size.height / 3.0;
    CGFloat ninthWidth = thirdWidth / 3.0;
    CGFloat ninthHeight = thirdHeight / 3.0;

    CGRect selectionRect = CGRectMake(_selectionCellX * thirdWidth + _selectionX * ninthWidth,
                                      _selectionCellY * thirdHeight + _selectionY * ninthHeight,
                                      ninthWidth, ninthHeight);

    UIColor* selectionColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:1.0 alpha:0.5];
    [selectionColor setFill];

    UIBezierPath* selectionPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:selectionRect cornerRadius:(ninthWidth/4.0)];
    [selectionPath fill];
}
```

Comment: You should show the iOS version of `paintSelectionRectangle`, as that is probably where the bug is.

Comment: Edited. it's shown now.

Answer (score 0):

You should not call `paintSelectionRectangle` in `touchesEnded:withEvent:`. This method does drawing operations and you don't have a graphics context there. Just send `setNeedsDisplay` to the views which need to redraw.

Also I think that calling `touchesBegan:withEvent:` manually is a bad idea.

**EDIT**: I took a closer look at your code and what you try to achieve. I would create a UIView subclass that draws the selection rectangle. Just fill the whole bounds with the bezier path:

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIColor* selectionColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:1.0 alpha:0.5];
    [selectionColor setFill];

    CGRect roundedrect = self.bounds;
    CGFloat cornerRadius = self.bounds.size.width / 36;
    UIBezierPath* selectionPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:roundedRect
                                                             cornerRadius:cornerRadius];
    [selectionPath fill];
}
```

Add an instance of that view to your main view and set its `hidden` property to YES.

In `touchesEnded:withEvent:` determine the selection rectangle, set the frame of the selection view and set `hidden` to NO, if you detected a selection:

```
CGRect selectionRect = CGRectMake(_selectionCellX * thirdWidth + _selectionX * ninthWidth,
                                  _selectionCellY * thirdHeight + _selectionY * ninthHeight,
                                  ninthWidth, ninthHeight);
[selectionSubview setFrame: selectionRect];

[selectionSubview setHidden: !_haveSelection];
```

If you like you can also animate the frame change using CoreAnimation.

Comment: I tried moving `paintSelectionRectangle` out of `touchesEnded` and back into `touchesBegan` and still get the CGContext errors.

Could you explain why calling `touchesBegan:withEvent:` manually is a bad idea?

Comment: He means that you should move `paintSelectionRectangle` to `drawRect:` and instead put a call to `setNeedsDisplay` into `touchesEnded:withEvent:`.

Comment: Ok, I think we're on the right track. This stopped the CGContext errors from appearing in the debugger, but there is still no selection rectangle appearing.

Comment: Does anyone else have any advice on this? I feel like I'm close but still just not quite there.